# How to include normally ignored DEBUG log event in wildfly log?

Tags: logging, wildfly

My application logs error events at various logging levels. ERR1 & ERR2 are DEBUG level. ERR3 is INFO level. ERR4 is ERROR level.

How can I configure the logging subsystem in Wildfly to always log ERR2 regardless of what level the root logger is configured for, without altering which other events from my application get logged?

So if my root logger is at DEBUG level I should see:

```
18:31:09,476 DEBUG  [org.myapp] (default task-1) ERR1: Test
18:31:09,476 DEBUG  [org.myapp] (default task-1) ERR2: Test
18:31:09,476 INFO  [org.myapp] (default task-1) ERR3: Test
18:31:09,476 ERROR  [org.myapp] (default task-1) ERR4: Test
```

But if my root logger is at ERROR level I should see:

```
18:31:09,476 DEBUG  [org.myapp] (default task-1) ERR2: Test
18:31:09,476 ERROR  [org.myapp] (default task-1) ERR4: Test
```

I tried this:

```
<logger category="org.myapp">
    <filter-spec value="match(&quot;ERR2&quot;))"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Now I see ERR2, but that hides all other logged events from my package. I also tried:

```
<logger category="org.myapp">
    <filter-spec value="any(match(&quot;ERR2&quot;)),levels(ERROR))"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

which is closer, since I get ERR2 and all ERROR level events but this requires me to keep the entries within `levels` in sync with whatever my root logger level is. So if I change the root logger to INFO and forget to alter the org.myapp logger I'll be missing all the INFO events from org.myapp.

So what's the best way to start including ERR2 events in my logs without affecting the other events in my package?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that filters on loggers are not inherited. So you have have a logger named `com.myapp.other` the filter would not be used.

If that's not an issue however you could do an inverse match in the filter spec. Something like `not(match("ERR1|ERR2")`. The CLI command would look something like:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.myapp:write-attribute(name=filter-spec, value=not(match("ERR1|ERR2")))
```